# Asynchronous execution with Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I currently have a Matlab application which receives request from another, external application (coded in JAVA).

The Java application notify matlab using a system described in 'Undocumented Matlab by Yair Atlman. We can notify Matlab of various actions, name them A and B, which triggers different callbacks.

The problem is the following: In some condition, it is possible that the java application send a new notification before the first one is processed. In an ideal world, here is what I would like to happen:

- Matlab receives A
- Matlab starts executing callback A
- Matlab receives B
- Matlab holds callback B and continue executing callback A
- Matlab executes callback B

Here is what happen:

- Matlab receives A
- Matlab starts executing callback A
- Matlab receives B
- Matlab pauses callback A
- Matlab executes callback B
- Matlab finishes callback A

I tried several possible solution but all failed and I finally managed to find a weird workaround, but this workaround came with issues and I have to get rid of it. I do not have access to parallel computing.
My tries involve storing received actions in a static queue and locking callback execution but it ends up in infinite loops since A is never cleared.

Since B could actually needs data produced by A, the perfect solution would actually be that Java holds the B notification until it receives a "complete" notification from Matlab. I tried to use parallelism here too but Matlab paused its execution and java never received the notification and sleeps forever ...

At this point I am willing to take any workaround because I am totally clueless for a robust solution.

Thanks

PS: Must work on both matlab 2011b and 2014b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution using Matlab Control, a framework that allow you to communicate directly with Matlab while at the same time avoiding most of the potential deadlock issues:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/matlabcontrol/

And here is the class implementation I made to use the framework to fit my needs (many other usages are possible):

```
package framework.matlab.events;

import matlabcontrol.MatlabConnectionException;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabInvocationException;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabProxy;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabProxyFactory;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabProxyFactoryOptions;

public class MatlabEvent {  

    private String      mMethodName;
    private int         mMethodOutputs;
    private MatlabProxy mProxy;

    public void setMethodParameters(String iMethodName, int iMethodOuputs) {
        mMethodName     = iMethodName;
        mMethodOutputs  = iMethodOuputs;        
    }

    public void callMatlabMethod(Object ... obj) {

        connect();

        try {
            mProxy.returningFeval(mMethodName, mMethodOutputs, obj);    
        } catch (MatlabInvocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally   {
            disconnect();
        }   
    }

    private void connect() {

        MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options = new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
                .setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(true)
                .build();

        MatlabProxyFactory factory  = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);      

        try {
            mProxy = factory.getProxy();
        } catch (MatlabConnectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void disconnect() {
        if (null != mProxy) {
            mProxy.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

As a consequence, I am no longer using the Matlab notification system created by Yair Altman.